# non recursive program to draw a ruler

Tags: algorithm

I am reading algorithms by Robert Sedwick.

**[Here is the book](http://tinyurl.com/cu8s88r)**

Page number:214.

Below text is in reference to from binary representation of numbers.

Here Robert Sedwick mentioned that following program is inspired by the correspondence to binary numbers. Nonrecursive program to draw a ruler whichis mentioned as below

```
void rule(int l, int r, int h)
  { 
    for (int t = 1, j = 1; t <= h; j += j, t++)
      for (int i = 0; l+j+i <= r; i += j+j)
        mark(l+j+i, t);
  }
```

In Fig 5.10 author mentioning that to draw a ruler nonrecurively, we alternate drawing marks of length 1 and skipping
positions, then alternate drawing marks of length 2 and skipping remaining postion, and so forth.

I have following questions on above.

1. My question is how author mentioned that program is inspired by correspondnce to binary numbers?
2. In Fig5.10 what does author mean by skipping postions? What positions refer here?
3. In Fig5.10 what is marks in firt diagram?

Please explain with rule(0,8,3).

Comment: this may be a better fit down at [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/). regardless, the question is not very constructive. offering to close.

Answer (score 1):

For #1, if you write down a range of numbers in binary, and mask off everything except their lower x bits, you get a repeating pattern (e.g. x=4):

```
 0 = 0000
 1 = 0001
 2 = 0010
 3 = 0011
 4 = 0100
 5 = 0101
...
14 = 1110
15 = 1111
16 = 0000
17 = 0001
...
```

If you look for numbers that ends in a string of 1's you see an interesting pattern.
Turning the above anti-clockwise 90 degrees to save space:

```
010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101
001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011 ....
000011110000111100001111000011110000111100001111
000000001111111100000000111111110000000011111111
```

Replacing (only) the ending strings of 1's with !:

```
0!0!0!0!0!0!0!0!0!0!0!0!0!0!0!0!0!0!0!0!0!0!0!0!
001!001!001!001!001!001!001!001!001!001!001!001! ....
0000111!0000111!0000111!0000111!0000111!0000111!
000000001111111!000000001111111!000000001111111!
```

Replace everything else with space, you get a ruler pattern that repeats itself.

```
 ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! !
   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   !   ! ....
       !       !       !       !       !       !
               !               !               !
```

If you think about it you can see how the length of the string of 1's (corresponds to the length of the marks) corresponds to its frequency of occurence and how it leads to the pattern above.

Comment: you mentioned that putting the above sideways to save space we got following. I am not getting how did you concluded 000000001111111100000000111111110000000011111111 ?

Comment: Read each column from top to bottom.  The leftmost one reads 0,0,0,0 = 0000 = 0.  The next one is 0001 = 1.  The next one 0010 = 2 etc.

Comment: If we put side by reading each column we should get 0000 0001 0010 0011 and so on, which is not matching with your first row 000000001111111100000000111111110000000011111111. can you please eloborate? And also you mentioned that "If you look for numbers that ends in a string of 1's you see an interesting pattern"  What is that pattern? Sorry for asking again.

Comment: Anotther question why each row consists of 48 0's and 1's? Sorry for lot of questions.

Comment: When I said 'putting the above sideways', I did not mean literally turning it 90 degrees...  But I'll edit the answer so that it is literally 90 degrees from the above for you to see it more easily.

Comment: I just happen to write 48 0's and 1's on each row, they can grow indefinitely to the right.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that the one who is missing something here is the author of this text, not the reader. The code posted from the book is missing comments - in particular @param tags to indicate exactly what the three parameters mean. The explanation posted seems to have something missing as well.

Here is my guess at #2:
When you look at a ruler, there is a larger mark for 0.5 inches than 0.25 or 0.75 inches. So first we can place the half inch marks, then when we place the 1/4" marks we "skip positions" because half of the 1/4" marks do not need to be drawn. For example, when we fill in the marks between 1" and 3", counting by 1/4" we have:

1.25 [skip] 1.75 [skip] 2.25 [skip],,...

Put another way, when placing the 1/4" marks we are really counting by 0.5" instead of a quarter. In the code posted from the book, this is probably why you see `j+j` in the inside loop. This suggest that j is the current marker value (first 1/4, then 1/2, then 1/8). Since everything is done with integers, maybe j=1 corresponds to 1/16" and then 2j, 4j, 8j are the marker values.